# PHP - How can I use foreach loop from two arrays to build a grid without repeating values in rows

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to build an office appointment Grid.
Each row should only list each employee(user) ONCE.
But each column should represent an appointment.
Users will have an ever changing number of appointments. My query will of course return a row for each. Every way I try this ends up in a row for each user with only one appointment on each row.

My arrays

```
$users[] = array ('id' => $row ['id'], 'fname' => $row ['fname']);
```

output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [fname] => Brent ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [fname] => Macy )
      ) 

$appointments[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'clientid' => $row['clientid'], 'userid' => $row['userid'], 'date' => $row['date']);
```

output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => [clientfname] => [userid] => [date] =>) 
[1] => Array ( [id] =>10 [clientfname] =>Lisa [userid] =>1 [date] =>2011-11-10 1:00:00) 
[2] => Array ( [id] =>11 [clientfname] =>Amanda [userid] =>1 [date] =>2011-11-10 1:03:00) 
[3] => Array ( [id] =>12 [clientfname] =>Britany [userid] =>2 [date] =>2011-11-10 1:00:00) 
      )

(Employee Calendar)
<< Monday Oct 8 >>
<<  1:00pm  1:30pm  2:00pm  2:30pm  >>
Macy    Lisa    Amanda              
Vanessa     Britany
```

Any ideas????

Comment: Can you post your SQL Query and table structure? You may be able to use the group by clause in your SQL statement to solve this

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$user_appointments = array();
foreach( $appointments as $appointment ) {
    $user_appointments[$appointment['clientid']][] = $appointment;
}

$appointments_grid = array();
foreach( $users as $user ) {
   $appointments_grid = array( 'clientfname' => $user['clientfname'], 'appointments' => $user_appointments[$user['userid']] );
}
```

I'd be the first to admit that there might be a neater solution. Perhaps if you had posted where you got this data from, something could be done there too. But this should work.